# How to copy the table with values from one database to another database table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I Create the table **abc under test** database.And I create **bcd table under test1**.The bcd,abc table fields are same.abc table have the data. Now,**How to copy the abc table values to bcd table in sql server 2005**?

Answer (score 3):

use `INSERT INTO...SELECT`

```
INSERT INTO test1.dbo.bcd(col1, col2, col3)
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM test.dbo.abc
```

Comment: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'bcd' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Comment: try to execute this on database test2 first: `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON`

Comment: I remove the primary key and off the Identity.After I move the record then i change bcd with primary key and Identity on

Answer (score 0):

Do like this:
   SELECT * 
   INTO DestinationDB..MyDestinationTable 
   FROM SourceDB..MySourceTable